# Sample C# Code To Print WinForm MSChart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have been searching the internet high and low for a simple way to print an MSChart that I have on a WinForm to no avail.  Can someone please give me some information or point me to a resource that includes sample C# code to print a MSChart?  After over an hour of web research, I still do not even know where to start.  I also want to disclaim that I am very new to printing anything other than text and crystal reports.

Comment: have you looked this? http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a combination of the CodeProject article below and the MSChart sample code provided by MSFT to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65803/A-Guide-to-using-MSChart-for-NET) contains a section showing how to print charts.
This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136158/c-sharp-ms-chart-what-is-the-best-way-to-print-a-chart) also.